# Cannot debug windows Service

Tags: .net, windows-services

I have a windows Service which I have installed using

```
installutil windowsservice1.exe
```

This service shows up in the `Services` panel and I am able to `start / stop` it.

However, when I press F5 to debug it, I get the following error

```
Cannot Start windows Service from the command line or debugger. A Windows Service must be installed......
```

However, it is already installed. Then why do I get this error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows service start failure: Cannot start service from the command line or debugger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11573724/windows-service-start-failure-cannot-start-service-from-the-command-line-or-deb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach the Visual Studio debugger to it as indicated in this [MSDN Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a50syb3.aspx) article

From above link:

> Because a service must be run from within the context of the Services Control Manager rather than from within Visual Studio, debugging a service is not as straightforward as debugging other Visual Studio application types. To debug a service, you must start the service and then attach a debugger to the process in which it is running. You can then debug your application using all of the standard debugging functionality of Visual Studio.

Comment: Providing you have the right permissions on your system, call `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()` in `Main()` or `OnStart()`.  When you start your service from the SCM, you'll be presented with a dialog box that allows you to select which instance of Visual Studio to use to debug the service.  Your service will pause at the `Launch()` call like it hit a breakpoint.  You can debug normally from there.