# Cannot Start the C# application in visual Studio 12

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have application in C# in visual studio 12.
Everything was working fine. I changed some values in Settings.settings. When i start the project it gives me below error.

[image]

Translatation : Unable to start service from the command line or debug.
A Windows Service must first be installed (using insallutil.exe) then started with the Server Explorer, the Administration Tool Windows Services or the NET START command.

I undo my changes , but still getting the same. I sure Setting.setting values is not reason for this. I just mentioning the activities i did.

Also my system got hanged when i was Starting the Project. I re-started the system and tried to Start the Application. After that i see this error.

I am not a expert of this languange. So please anybody can help to fix this problem.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11573724/windows-service-start-failure-cannot-start-service-from-the-command-line-or-deb[/link]

Comment: You try to run or debug windows service project as a console application?

Comment: Have you tried this <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157176/run-a-windows-service-as-a-console-app>?

Comment: Side note: You shouldn't abbreviate Visual Studio year numbers to 2 digits. VS has both an internal version number and a "year" number. Visual Studio 12 was the product that was released branded as "Visual Studio 2013", whereas "Visual Studio 2012" has a version number of 11.